# How to check if WebElement does not exist with C# and Appium and throw proper error

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a code that checks if the AppiumWebElement exists on the page, by its ID (I'm checking against the list of expected elements, and I want to see that none of those elements is missing on the page).
When element exists - it works fine.
But if element does not exist - it throws me:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/92e77b3a-d69b-4261-9ade-59621875206a/element/7.2308.43816588/element timed out after 60 seconds.
```

And I would like to get something more meaningful, something like "*Element XXX does not exist/cannot be found*", rather than TimeOut.

I have tried with 2 approaches:

1. ```
   private static bool RowsContainCorrectColumns(IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement> rows, IList<string> columnsIdsList)
   {
   var firstRow = rows.FirstOrDefault();

       if (columnsIdsList.Any())
   {
       foreach (var id in columnsIdsList)
       {
           try
           {
               firstRow.FindElementByAccessibilityId(id);
           }
           catch (NoSuchElementException)
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }

   return true;
   ```

   }
2. ```
   private static bool RowsContainCorrectColumns(IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement> rows, IList<string> columnsIdsList)
   {
   var firstRow = rows.FirstOrDefault();

       if (columnsIdsList.Any())
   {
       foreach (var id in columnsIdsList)
       {
           if (!firstRow.FindElementByAccessibilityId(id).Displayed)
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   return true;
   ```

   }

Methods that utilizes RowsContainCorrectColumns:

```
public static void AssertRowsContainCorrectColumnsById<T>(this ReportsTestFixture fixture, IEnumerable<string> columnsIds) where T : ViewCommonControls, new()
        {
            (
                    from view in fixture.MainWindow.InitializeView<T>()
                    from rows in Result.Try(() => view.DataGridControl.FindElementsByClassName("DataRow"))
                    select RowsContainCorrectColumns(rows, columnsIds)
                )
                .Should().BeSuccessful()
                .AndSuccessValue.Should().BeTrue();
        }
```

Comment: Do you use any implicit or explicit wait used?

Comment: I do not think there is one @SubanDhyako

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the list of the element and then check if the size of the list is greater than zero or not. If the size>0 then the element is present on the page else it is not.
You can do it like:

```
IList<IWebElement> elementList = driver.FindElements(By.Id("put the id here"));
if(elementList.Count>0)
{
    // Element is present
}
else
{
    // Element is not present
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer Arona. But what I'm looking for is not to see if the list contains any element, but rather to make sure that All elements, I'm searching for, are presented on the page. And I do know how to avoid getting TimeOut instead of "element not found" .